# Ground state of electrons in an atom

Tags: atomic-physics, ground-state

When we talk about the ground state of the electrons in the atom, do we mean its state at room temperature?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we are referring to the ground state of an atom or molecule we normally mean a single isolated atom or molecule, and this does not have a temperature since temperature is a statistical property of an assemblage of many objects. So in this sense your question cannot be answered.

However if we had a gas of atoms and molecules then their state is affected by collisions with other molecules in the gas, and since the collision frequency and energy is affected by temperature then the temperature does have an affect on the electronic state of the atoms and molecules in the gas. This is more of an issue for molecules as in general the gap between states in atoms is larger than $kT$ at room temperature. However even for atoms there are transitions that can be excited at room temperature. For example the caesium hypefine splitting is only about $0.00004$ electron volts and this corresponds to a temperature of only about $0.5$ K. So in this sense the ground state would be the state in an ideal gas at absolute zero.

In real life atoms and molecules at absolute zero form a crystal (apart from helium) and the interactions in the crystal would perturb the state away from that of an isolated atom or molecule. So unless the atom is isolated even at absolute zero the state is not the ground state.